# Rescaling axis in Matplotlib imshow under unique function call

Tags: python, scale, axis, matplotlib

I have written a function module that takes the argument of two variables. To plot, I had

```
x, y = pylab.ogrid[0.3:0.9:0.1, 0.:3.5:.5]
z = np.zeros(shape=(np.shape(x)[0], np.shape(y)[1]))

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y[0])):    
        z[i][j] = fancyFunction(x[i][0], y[0][j])

pylab.imshow(z, interpolation="gaussian")
```

The image I get is the following:
[image]

But when I tried rescaling the x and y axis to match the ranges of [0.3:0.9:0.1, 0.:3.5:.5] thru `pylab.imshow(z, interpolation="gaussian", extent=[.3,.9,0.,3.5])` I get

[image]

I've been googling for hours but still couldn't find a way to make a square plot with differently scaled axis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `aspect` argument:

```
pylab.imshow(z, interpolation="gaussian", extent = [.3,.9,0.,3.5], aspect='auto')
```