# Plot this kind of graph from data of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, plot

Good afternoon,

I am working on a Matlab project and I have stored some data in an array. I would like to plot a plot like the plot shown below. However, I don't know what **plotting function** I need to use and **how**, in order to obtain the image plot (it will be not the same, but this style).

My data is on a 11x16 - matrix.

Thank you guys so much beforehand!

[image]

---

@rayryeng

It was a really useful answer, although I didn't need that exact shape. I need the shape that my data would create, I've been trying to modify the code you wrote in order to obtain what I need but I did not obtained it...

My data is

```
data = ( 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ; 
8.00 8.02 8.04 8.07 8.12 8.20 8.30 8.42 8.53 8.63 8.72 8.80 8.86 8.91 8.96 9.00;
6.00 6.03 6.07 6.12 6.22 6.37 6.59 6.83 7.07 7.28 7.45 7.60 7.72 7.83 7.92 8.00;
4.00 4.03 4.07 4.14 4.26 4.48 4.85 5.26 5.63 5.95 6.21 6.43 6.61 6.75 6.88 7.00;
2.00 2.02 2.05 2.10 2.20 2.44 3.08 3.70 4.23 4.67 5.01 5.29 5.52 5.70 5.86 6.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1.33 2.24 2.93 3.47 3.88 4.21 4.46 4.67 4.84 5.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.01 1.78 2.38 2.84 3.19 3.46 3.67 3.84 4.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.80 1.43 1.91 2.25 2.51 2.70 2.86 3.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.63 1.10 1.41 1.62 1.77 1.89 2.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.44 0.66 0.79 0.88 0.94 1.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0)
```

This is my matrix of data (sorry I know it's too long), well and when I try to plot writing:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:16,1:11);
contourf(x,y,data,20,'LineStyle','none');
colorbar
```

It should have a different shape than what I get. **I need to get that the part that are 0 (zeros) are like the white part of the plot I showed before. (Different shape though)** I don't really know how to do it (my data should be read properly), if you could help me I would be really thankful.

Thank you so much for last answer.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765025/rescaling-axis-in-matplotlib-imshow-under-unique-function-call

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015070/create-a-colorbar-from-an-rgba-function-in-matplotlib

Comment: Where's the data?  Can you attach it with your post?  Try using `imagesc` which will plot your data and apply a colour map to it... but I can't say for sure since you don't have your data here.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your data, I believe you should use `contourf`.

This is as close as I could get,

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:16,1:11);
data = - y;
data(end,5:10) = NaN;
data(end-1,6:9) = NaN;
data(end-2,7:8) = NaN;
contourf(x,y,data,20,'LineStyle','none');
colorbar
```

[image]

with,

```
data = - y .* abs(log(sin(.10 * x - 5.5)+.5));
data(data < -4) = NaN;
```

[image]

So I suppose the code is right, it's matter of your data,

with `data = max(data(:)) - data;`

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much! 

I would like you to read the next answer by me (since it's not going to fit here all the text I'm going to write)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is almost correct.  All you need to do is set any data that is 0 to `NaN`.  That way, when you throw it into `contourf`, those parts are not visualized.  As such:

```
data = [10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ;
8.00 8.02 8.04 8.07 8.12 8.20 8.30 8.42 8.53 8.63 8.72 8.80 8.86 8.91 8.96 9.00;
6.00 6.03 6.07 6.12 6.22 6.37 6.59 6.83 7.07 7.28 7.45 7.60 7.72 7.83 7.92 8.00;
4.00 4.03 4.07 4.14 4.26 4.48 4.85 5.26 5.63 5.95 6.21 6.43 6.61 6.75 6.88 7.00;
2.00 2.02 2.05 2.10 2.20 2.44 3.08 3.70 4.23 4.67 5.01 5.29 5.52 5.70 5.86 6.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1.33 2.24 2.93 3.47 3.88 4.21 4.46 4.67 4.84 5.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1.01 1.78 2.38 2.84 3.19 3.46 3.67 3.84 4.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.80 1.43 1.91 2.25 2.51 2.70 2.86 3.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.63 1.10 1.41 1.62 1.77 1.89 2.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.44 0.66 0.79 0.88 0.94 1.00;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
data(data == 0) = NaN;

[x,y] = meshgrid(1:16,1:11);
contourf(x,y,data,20,'LineStyle','none');
colorbar
```

---

This is what I get:

[image]

Given your comments, you want the y-axis to be reversed.  Simply put `axis ij;` at the end of the code above to flip the `y`-axis so that `y`-down is the positive direction.  If you do that, we get this figure:

[image]

---

Credit should go to Kamtal as he figured out where you needed to start.  I just helped finish off the requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I got now I was not used to working with this function... 

However, how could I do it to get it inverse ( I mean the zeros are in the lower part on my array but in the plot the white part is on the upper side ) is there any way to turn it upside down?

Thanks so much! @rayryeng

Comment: @user3780731, use `data = data(end:-1:1,:);` see if it is what you want. you can also use `data = max(data(:)) - data` to change colors.

Comment: You can reverse the axis by doing `axis ij`.  Let me modify my post.

Comment: @user3780731 - You're welcome.  Please accept Kamtal's (or mine if you want) answer to signify that you no longer need help.